# Android App not runnig in Bluestacks

Tags: eclipse, bluestacks

I'm using Eclipse to develop an Android application, and I want to use Bluestacks as my emulator. I tried `adb 127.0.0.1` successfully. When I double click my project's APK, it says that my app has been installed, but when I try to run it in Bluestacks my app store it says "device could not find your app". Alternatively I also tried to run it by using Eclipse IDE, and it said "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Bluestacks and following the procedure again. By following the procedure I mean running the command `adb connect 127.0.0.1` and reinstalling the APK you want to test. It worked for me.